# Supporting typeahead autocomplete with ElasticSearch

Tags: autocomplete, elasticsearch, typeahead

Is there a standard way to implement character-by-character typeahead autocomplete using ElasticSearch for small fields (e.g. place names).

(At the time of writing this, there are a number of discussions available via search, but nothing that seems definitive. (Also, I see there is talk of the effect of feature support for autocomplete/suggest in Apache Lucene 4.))

Thanks for thoughts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use Edge NGram based analyzer, see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/edgengram-tokenizer.html

Or use the suggest plugin: https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-suggest-plugin

HTH

Answer (score 3):

As David wrote, you can use NGrams or the suggest plugin. With lucene 4 it will be possible to have better auto-suggestions out-of-the-box, without the need to mantain a separate index.

For now you can also just make a [terms facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets/terms-facet.html) on your field and use a regex pattern to keep only the entries that start with the relevant prefix:

```
"facets" : {
    "tag" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "field_name",
            "regex" : "prefix.*"
        }
    }
}
```

The regex is just an example, it can be improved and you can also make it case insensitive using the proper [regex flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#field_summary). Also, beware that making on a facet on a field that contains many unique terms is not a great idea, unless you have enough memory for it.

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in autocompletion suggester that's available since version 0.90.3:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-suggesters-completion.html

It's blazingly fast and was developed for exactly that use case.

Comment: BTW @simon the new completion prefix suggestion feature is not at 0.90.0 but in 0.90.3 (and still considered experimental). https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3376

Comment: True is very fast, but is the same thing than use mySQL LIKE prefix* or Redis/CouchBase auto-complete.

Comment: The link in the answer no more exists. This may be a help for newbies! http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-suggesters.html

Comment: Updated documentation link and text.